# Elementary problem in functions

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

> If $f(−1) = −7$ and $f(x) = g(−6 \cdot x)$, what point must satisfy $y = g(x)$?

Can anyone explain how to get the answer to this question, step by step? I'm having problems visualizing how to get the answer, even after examining the solution in the back of the book.

Comment: Hint:  you are told $f(-1)$ and no other explicit values, so that has to be the key.  What value of $x$ should you choose to ensure that $g(x)=f(-1)$?

Answer (score 1):

We know: $f(-1) = -7$ and $f(x) = g(-6 \cdot x)$.

What do we need? A point such that $y = g(x)$ -- essentially *any* point on the graph of $g$.

The natural way to combine our facts is to apply what you know about $f(x)$ **in general** to the thing you're told about $f(-1)$ specifically.

The second fact, here, tells us that we can replace $f(x)$, for any value of $x$, with $g(-6 \cdot x)$, and the result will be equal!

Doing that here, we get $g(-6 \cdot (-1)) = -7$, or $g(6) = -7$.

And our answer is right there! Saying $g(6) = -7$ means: "The point $(6, -7)$ is on the graph of $g$."

---

When initially solving problems like this, it can be confusing: you often feel like you can't possibly have *enough* info to solve the question as-is. An important lesson in mathematical problem solving, however, is to focus on exactly the info you're given, and ignore all the rest. More often than not, any *mathematically sound* steps you make from that point on will turn out to be the *correct* ones!